# JavaScript: breaking out of a callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

So I solved this challenge 'Finders Keepers' on Free Code Camp, but I'm dissatisfied with my solution.

The problem [link [here]](http://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/finders-keepers)

asks to write a function that takes two parameters, an array and a function, and returns the first element in the array that returns true when passed to the second parameter's function.

My solution:

```
function find(arr, func) {
  return arr.filter(function(val) {
      return func(val);
  })[0];
}

find([1, 2, 3, 4], function(num){ return num % 2 === 0; });
```

certainly works, but it iterates over all the array elements, only to return the first. That's fine if the array is only four elements long, but what if it was much longer?

Is there some way to get the callback function to break after returning x values?

Comment: you could use `.some()` or `.every()` instead of `.filter()` + a closure to push out the index. there's the new `[].find()` and `[].findIndex()` too, so really, you could code that same thing as `var find=Function.call.bind([].find);`, and your other code runs as expected

Comment: faster: `function find(r,f){for(var i=0,mx=r.length;i<mx;i++)if(f(r[i]))return r[i]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem basically describes [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function, so your code could be:

```
function find(arr, callback) {
  return arr.find(callback)
}
```

Comment: and then you can run it like this: 

`find(["", 0, 1, 2], function(d) {
     if(d) return d;
})`

it exits after the first truthy value